# Anyone Know How to Switch butttons with Keyboard without use the Mouse on Mac?

Tags: xcode, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I am used use keyboard as much as possible so I wonder if it possible switch with a keyboard shortcut between two buttons ? For example when you press `command+o` to open a Xcode workspace file, a pop up will be visible and i need to switch "open" with keyboard not with a mouse or trackpad move:)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried Full Keyboard Access (System prefs -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts)?

Comment: yes and I tried karabinar as well and could not find a way to do this.

Answer (score -1):

> I don’t know for sure, but assume you could do it with Tab or Alt+Tab

**I was wrong, you couldn't do it this way**

Comment: Sorry for wrong answer. Check this out, you may find what you need here https://vscode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/editor/accessibility/